# A lower triangular diagram in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, matrices

How would I type the following diagram in LaTeX (perhaps Ti*k*Z)?: I want 10 bullet points, arranged as the points in the lower triangular part of a 5 times 5 matrix. Then I want arrows pointing from every node to the one directly above it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Comment: You can add a graph also hand made?

Comment: ChatGPT is pretty good with tikz. Have your tried just typing your request directly in ChatGPT.

Comment: @BenjaminMcKay: I tried but the code I got would not compile and I could not see how to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

[image: Result]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\newlength\radius
\setlength\radius{2pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \i in {0,...,4}{ % rows
        \foreach \j in {0,...,4}{ % columns
            \ifnum\numexpr\j-\i<0\relax % check for lower triangle
                \def\fill{fill}
            \else
                \def\fill{}
            \fi
            \draw[\fill] (\j, -\i) circle (\radius);
            \ifnum\i>0\relax % if not in first row, draw arrow
                \draw[->, blue, shorten <=\radius, shorten >=\radius] (\j, -\i) -- +(0,1);
            \fi
        }
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

#### Code after removing white dots.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\newlength\radius
\setlength\radius{2pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \i in {0,...,4}{ % rows
        \foreach \j in {0,...,4}{ % columns
            \ifnum\numexpr\j-\i<0\relax % check for lower triangle
                \filldraw (\j, -\i) circle (\radius);
                \ifnum\i>0\relax % if not in first row, draw arrow
                    \draw[->, blue, shorten <=\radius, shorten >=\radius] (\j, -\i) -- +(0,1);
                \fi
            \fi
        }
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result 2]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Could you remove the white dots?

Comment: @DykeAcland Sure, please see my updated answer. Are you sure that this will still be recognized as a 5x5 matrix?

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Thanks a lot!

Comment: One last question. How would I get rid of the arrows that do not end in a bullet?

Comment: @JeanRobert Change `\ifnum\i>0\relax` to `\ifnum\numexpr\j-\i<-1\relax`.

Answer (score 1):

A variation of Οὖτις's nice answer, using `node`s instead of `circle`s to simplify drawing the arrows a bit:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \u using int(\i-1)] in {0,...,3}{ 
        \foreach \j [evaluate=\j as \v using int(\j-\i)] in {\i,...,3}{ 
            \node[circle, fill, inner sep=2pt] at (\v, \i) (n-\v-\i) {};
            \ifnum\i>0\relax 
                \draw[->, blue] (n-\v-\u) -- (n-\v-\i);
            \fi
        }
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]